# Storing and retrieving Emojis in Couchbase/Mule

Tags: json, mule, couchbase

We have exposed various REST APIs using Mule and one of our client wants to send Emojis as part of JSON POST request. We noticed that when the data is stored in Couchbase, the Emoji from the request is stored as some encoded characters.

- What's the best way to pass Emojis in JSON POST request?
- How the Emojis are stored in Couchbase?
- Is there any configuration to store and retrieve Emojis as "Emojis" in Couchbase?
- Is there any configuration to store and retrieve Emojis as "Emojis" in Mule?

Comment: When you say emoji, are you referring to UTF encoded characters say in UTF-8?  For instance, those described here: http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Today, my colleague found an issue with our implementation. He found that we need to explicitly set "encoding" attribute on one of the transformer.

Once we receive JSON request in Mule Application, at one point we were using `<byte-array-to-string-transformer />` which was corrupting Emojis, but after changing this transformer to `<byte-array-to-string-transformer encoding="UTF-8" />` Emojis are stored correctly.